# Автоматическая смена цвета SVG в зависимости от цвета изображения под SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Есть логотип, в **svg**.

Мне необходимо менять цвет логотипа ***белый*** или ***чёрный*** в зависимости от доминирующего цвета под логотипом.

Пробовал для этих целей использовать плагин [`BackgroundCheck`](http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/). В чистом `html` плагин работает, но на когда загружаю на ***`Тильду`*** - не работает.

Как мне кажется, игнорируются мои стили. Что я делаю не так?

```html
<!--logo-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .images {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .fixed-nav {
      /*  background-color: red; */
      position: fixed;
      left: 100px;
      top: 47px;
      width: 80px;
      z-index: 99999;
    }
    
    .fixed-nav.background--dark .fixed-nav-line {
      /*   background: #fff; */
    }
    
    .fixed-nav.background--dark .fixed-nav-logo {
      background-image: url(https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3831-3566-4637-b934-383138346332/Awhite.svg);
      height: 43px;
      width: 33px;
      /*   fill: white; */
      /*   color: #fff; */
    }
    
    .fixed-nav.background--light .fixed-nav-logo {
      background-image: url(https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6133-3534-4237-b863-666531326632/A.svg);
      height: 43px;
      width: 33px;
    }
    
    .fixed-nav-line,
    .fixed-nav-logo {
      background-image: url(https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6133-3534-4237-b863-666531326632/A.svg);
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .fixed-nav-line {
      width: 40px;
      height: 3px;
      background: #222;
    }
    
    .fixed-nav-logo {
      /*  background-color: yellow; */
      width: 33px;
      height: 43px;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 99999;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://hosting.maass.ua/background-check.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://hosting.maass.ua/fixed-nav.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--<div class="fixed">-->
  <div class="fixed-nav">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="fixed-nav-logo"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--</div> -->
  <div class="images">
    <img class="images" src="https://static.tildacdn.com/tild6361-3535-4136-a662-353763663866/12049949b04d4882bcdf.jpg" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <img class="images" src="https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3837-6362-4139-b933-616635623530/maass-RO-hall-30.jpg" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> P.S. Может существуют другие способы решения моей задачи?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Я посмотрел исходники backgroundCheck, он рисует все картинки с сайта на канве, чтобы определить какой пиксель в итоге получился. Скорее всего он не работает из-за `cors`, попробуйте разместить все картинки на том же ресурсе, на котором Вы размещаете сайт. Плюс вряд ли он (backgroundCheck) обрабатывает все ситуации вроде экзотических режимов смешивания, или css анимаций.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  filter: invert(.7);
```

```css
.images {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.fixed-nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 47px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  filter: invert(.7);
}

.fixed-nav-logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='150px' height='200px' viewBox='0 0 33 44'%3E%3C!-- Generator: Sketch 55.2 (78181) - https://sketchapp.com --%3E%3Ctitle%3EGroup 6%3C/title%3E%3Cdesc%3ECreated with Sketch.%3C/desc%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpolygon id='path-1' points='0.0003 0.2282 32.824 0.2282 32.824 29 0.0003 29'/%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cg id='Page-1' stroke='none' stroke-width='1' fill='none' fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg id='iPhone-8-Copy-3' transform='translate(-273.000000, -27.000000)'%3E%3Cg id='Group-6' transform='translate(273.000000, 29.000000)'%3E%3Cg id='Group-3' transform='translate(0.000000, 12.292900)'%3E%3Cmask id='mask-2' fill='white'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23path-1'/%3E%3C/mask%3E%3Cg id='Clip-2'/%3E%3Cpath d='M20.7453,18.2922 L18.9043,13.3612 C18.0503,11.2202 17.1073,8.5922 16.2093,6.0882 C15.3113,8.5922 14.3693,11.2202 13.5613,13.3612 L11.7193,18.2922 L20.7453,18.2922 Z M22.9003,23.9892 L9.6093,23.9892 L7.7683,29.0002 L0.0003,29.0002 L11.7643,0.2282 L20.7903,0.2282 L32.8243,29.0002 L24.7863,29.0002 L22.9003,23.9892 Z' id='Fill-1' fill='%231D1D1B' mask='url(%23mask-2)'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cpath d='M23.1925,7.7951 C23.1925,11.6391 20.0765,14.7551 16.2325,14.7551 C12.3875,14.7551 9.2715,11.6391 9.2715,7.7951 C9.2715,3.9511 12.3875,0.8341 16.2325,0.8341 C20.0765,0.8341 23.1925,3.9511 23.1925,7.7951 Z' id='Stroke-4' stroke='%231D1D1B' stroke-width='5.669'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-nav">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="fixed-nav-logo"></div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="images">
  <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/600" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <img class="images" src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/600/600" />
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то. Мне необходимо чтобы лого было однотонное и только двух цветов: чёрное или белое. В вашем же варианте лого получается инверсинное к цвету картники включая сам рисунок картинки.

Comment: В общем, не смог я одолеть BackgroundColor и решил испоьзовать предложенный Вам вариант. Теперь мне он даже очень нравится. Ещё раз, большое спасибо!

Comment: @AndrewGor лишь бы в радость =) только он вряд ли 100% кросс-браузерный

Comment: Десктопные Safari, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, iOS Safari - тестировал, всё работает без проблем.

Comment: @AndrewGor я больше про старьё

Comment: @StrangerintheQ можно обновить ссылки на фото ?Я не могу видеть эффект.

Answer (score 8):

Недавно столкнулся с аналогичным вопросом. Единственный и весьма спорный вариант реализации который нашел, требует подключения [tweenmax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax/) и дублирования логотипа (в вашем случае). Еще один недостаток - при скролле время от времени наблюдаются подёргивания. Тем не менее, альтернативы не нашел.

```js
function logoSwitch () {
  $('.icon-container.abso').each(function() {
    
    var distance = $('.icon-container').offset().top - $(this).closest('.row').offset().top;
    
    TweenLite.to(this,0,{y:distance, force3D:true});
  });
};

$(document).scroll(function() {
  logoSwitch();
});

logoSwitch();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.row {
  min-height: 110vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.icon-container.abso {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
}
.icon-container .logo {
  width: 300px;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.startLogo:active {
  animation: repaint 1ms;
}

.whiteLogo {
  fill: white;
  stroke: white;
}

.blackLogo {
  color: #1d1d1d;
}

.grey {
  background: #ccc;
}

.blue {
  background: skyBlue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="row grey ">
  <div class="icon-container">
      <svg class="logo blackLogo startLogo repaint animate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 734.61 235.64">
    <path d="M527.21 151.39s21.37 20.83 28.13 28.12c15.17 16.38 73.92 52.5 130.7 0 0 0 27.07-23.11 27.07-65.3 0-32.7-15.34-53.58-27.06-65.3-13.28-13.28-69.66-54.4-130.71 0L425.05 179.53c-61.05 54.39-117.43 13.27-130.71 0-11.72-11.72-27.06-32.6-27.06-65.3 0-42.19 27.07-65.3 27.07-65.3 56.77-52.5 115.53-16.38 130.7 0 6.76 7.29 28.13 28.12 28.13 28.12" fill="none" stroke="#181818" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="43" class="OO"/>
    <g id="R">
    <g id="R-2" data-name="R">
      <path class="cls-2" d="M247.46 335.39c-27.75 27.73-71.52 27-99.27-.72-6.87-6-41.49-38.56-41.49-38.56C73.79 265 55.89 256.38 25 256.38v42.94c22.44 0 33.21 8.68 67.63 41.82 5.62 5.41 22.8 20.93 26 23.69 44.44 44.4 114.59 45.15 159 .75z" transform="translate(-25 -162.87)"/>
      <path class="cls-2" d="M151.72 213.2c27.2 0 50.33 21.79 50.33 48.44 0 15.12-7.46 28.67-18.88 37.57l30.46 30.44a90.09 90.09 0 0 0 31.14-68c0-50.31-41.62-91.09-93-91.13H25v42.68z" transform="translate(-25 -162.87)"/>
    </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row blue">
  <div class="icon-container abso">
    <svg class="logo whiteLogo altLogo animate " xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 734.61 235.64">

    <path d="M527.21 151.39s21.37 20.83 28.13 28.12c15.17 16.38 73.92 52.5 130.7 0 0 0 27.07-23.11 27.07-65.3 0-32.7-15.34-53.58-27.06-65.3-13.28-13.28-69.66-54.4-130.71 0L425.05 179.53c-61.05 54.39-117.43 13.27-130.71 0-11.72-11.72-27.06-32.6-27.06-65.3 0-42.19 27.07-65.3 27.07-65.3 56.77-52.5 115.53-16.38 130.7 0 6.76 7.29 28.13 28.12 28.13 28.12" fill="none"  stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="43" class="OO"/>
    <g id="R">
    <g id="R-2" data-name="R">
      <path class="cls-2" d="M247.46 335.39c-27.75 27.73-71.52 27-99.27-.72-6.87-6-41.49-38.56-41.49-38.56C73.79 265 55.89 256.38 25 256.38v42.94c22.44 0 33.21 8.68 67.63 41.82 5.62 5.41 22.8 20.93 26 23.69 44.44 44.4 114.59 45.15 159 .75z" transform="translate(-25 -162.87)"/>
      <path class="cls-2" d="M151.72 213.2c27.2 0 50.33 21.79 50.33 48.44 0 15.12-7.46 28.67-18.88 37.57l30.46 30.44a90.09 90.09 0 0 0 31.14-68c0-50.31-41.62-91.09-93-91.13H25v42.68z" transform="translate(-25 -162.87)"/>
    </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спорное конечно решение, тем более что автор в примере предложил лого в растровом формате, а не в SVG Но попытка всячески приветствуется (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, не думаю что реализовать подобный функционал с растровым избражением является возможным в принципе. Ждем решение от руки мастера по svg)

Comment: тут нужен не мастер SVG. А в принципе другое решение, - JS.    Как я понимаю из коммента автора вопроса, - нужна не инверсия цвета **растрового** лого, как [в предыдущем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1027911/28748), а окраска только ЧБ в зависимости от яркости окружающих пикселей фона. А это можно реализовать только на JS.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, всё верно, в основе SVG логотип. И в зависимости от фона под логотипом он должен быть или чёрным или белым. И в принципе, используемый мною скрипт BackgroundCheck работает и решает мою задачу на 100% на обычных серверах, но как только я заливаю код на Тильду, всё перестаёт работать. И я не могу понять это Тильда игнорит CSS или она игнорит только JS. Поэтому я начал искать другие варианты.

Comment: @Игорь на самом деле можно инвертнуть цвета у части растровой картинки, например, по такому же принципу как у Вас в ответе...

Comment: @Игорь повесили баунти, а оно просто сгорело...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, увы не знаю что это такое. Дайте линк пожалуйста.

Comment: @Игорь Вы награду назначали...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну так никто и не предложил подходящий вариант решения проблемы / аналогов реализации такого функционала. Не верю что решения нет.

Comment: @Игорь можно с растром сделать то же самое что Вы с вектором сделали =) в рантайме

Answer (score 1):

Полностью - смотрите здесь:
https://jsfiddle.net/xmoonlight/zatdu0v2/

Это основная часть кода:

```
function setLogoColor(eImg,eSVGLogo,bw) {
    var c=getAverageRGB(eImg,eSVGLogo);
  if(bw) {
    eSVGLogo.style.fill=(c.l<128)?'rgb(255,255,255)':'rgb(0,0,0)';

    } else eSVGLogo.style.fill='rgb('+c.r+','+c.g+','+c.b+')';  
}

setLogoColor(document.querySelector('.img img'),document.querySelector('.img svg'),1);
```

Comment: пример по ссылке не рабочий.

Comment: @Игорь, пример работает во всех браузерах. Вы в каком тестировали?

Answer (score 1):

Через CSS3-фильтры можно добиться приемлемого результата, если использовать цепочку фильтров.

Цвет SVG логотипа делаем чёрным. Если он белый - меняем фильтр invert() с 1 на 0.
Фильтр brightness() помогает снизить волну цветовых переходов (60% - это +/-10%) при сильной разнице цветов на изображении, находящегося за логотипом.
**Порядок следования фильтров и порядок следования стилей - крайне важны!**

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/xmoonlight/7wgnxfsd/

```
<style>
.img svg { /* SVG LOGO: style="fill:#000000" */
  position: absolute;
  filter: invert(1) sepia(100%) brightness(60%) saturate(0);
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
</style>
```